# Updating kubernetes deployment with same image name

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, rolling-updates

We have a micro-services java applications, as and when we have changes in code we have to perform the kubernetes deployment.

How will I apply the latest changes to the deployment with the same Image name

we have a single replica and when I execute `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` it says unchanged.

We have kubelet version of v1.13.12

Please help.

Comment: A best practice is to use a distinct image tag for each build; then when you `kubectl apply` the updated deployment, there will be a change that causes Kubernetes to restart the pods for you.  You also can't roll back a failed build if you don't use a distinct tag for each.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed in [#33664](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664)

> using :latest tag IMO is not the best practice as it's hard to track what image is really in use in your pod. I think tagging images by versions or using the digests is strictly better than reusing the same tag. Is it really such a hassle to do that?

The recommended way is to **not** use image tag `:latest` when using declarative deployment with `kubectl apply`.